# input/output error with ffmpeg using an input URL in docker

Tags: docker, ffmpeg

I need to use ffmpeg to listen to an rtmp url within a running docker container using ffmpeg.
my ffmpeg command is quite simple: `ffmpeg -listen 1 -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live/app ./output.wav`

ffmpeg seems to start correctly and listen to the url.

But, when I start the stream (using OBS Studio) I have an input/output error. Here is the logs (with debug log level)

```
❯ ffmpeg -loglevel debug -listen 1 -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/app ./output.wav
ffmpeg version 5.1.4-0+deb12u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12 (Debian 12.2.0-14)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb12u1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --disable-sndio --enable-libjxl --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libplacebo --enable-librav1e --enable-shared
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Reading option '-listen' ... matched as AVOption 'listen' with argument '1'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/app'.
Reading option './output.wav' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/app.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/app.
[NULL @ 0x56288f8e7a00] Opening 'rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/app' for reading
[rtmp @ 0x56288f8e8200] No default whitelist set
[tcp @ 0x56288f8e8d40] No default whitelist set
[rtmp @ 0x56288f8e8200] Proto = rtmp, path = /live/app, app = live, fname = app
[rtmp @ 0x56288f8e8200] New incoming chunk size = 4096
rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/app: Input/output error
```

The last 3 lines only appear when I start the stream.

It doesn't seems to be a permission problem with the file system, since using `ffmpeg -i ./test.mp4 ./output.wav` works inside the container.

I also did not find any problem with the network. I am currently using `network_mode: "host"` in my docker_compose.yml and the logs show that it did receive data before the error appear.

It also doesn't seem to be a problem with the ffmpeg command, since the exact same command works when using it without docker involved.

What else could be the problem?

here is my docker_compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  ffmpeg-container:
    build:
      context: .
    network_mode: "host"
    tty: true  # Allocate a pseudo-TTY for interactive use
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

# Install ffmpeg
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg

# Create a working directory
WORKDIR app

# Copy the Python script to the container
COPY app.py .
COPY test.mp4 .

# Run the Python script
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```